Create emails unless cell has a value
There is a task which often is not completed on time. I remind colleagues if the deadline passes. I want to use Excel and VBA to generate emails. I need to use VBA thanks to the limitations of the hyperlink function.
There are some circumstances in which it is acceptable for the deadline to pass. In my workbook I have a column labelled "Extenuating circumstances". The values in this column will be defined by data validation. I need the macro to recognise that if a cell in column I is not blank, it should not produce an email.
Sub Send_Email_to_List()
Dim OL As Object, MailSendItem As Object
Dim user_msg As String
Dim MsgTxt As String

Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For Each xCell In ActiveSheet.Range(Range("H4"), Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    If Cells(xCell.Row, 12).Value = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Body_1 = Cells(xCell.Row, 12).Value
    Body_2 = Cells(xCell.Row, 13).Value

    user_email = xCell.Value
    user_subject = Cells(xCell.Row, 11).Value
    user_msg = Body_1 & Body_2

    Set MailSendItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With MailSendItem
        .Subject = user_subject
        .Body = user_msg
        .To = user_email
        .Display
    End With

Next xCell

Set OL = Nothing

End Sub

I believe I need to insert some variant of
If IsEmpty(Cells(xCell.Row, 9)) Then
    Exit Sub


shouldnt be  NOT  EMPTY ?-->   If !IsEmpty(Cells(xCell.Row, 9)) Then   Exit Sub

="", IsBlank(), IsEmpty() all have their quirks.
The easiest way to verify if the content of a cell is empty, is by verifying:
IF LEN(some_Cell.Value) = 0 THEN
...

Good luck
For clarification purposes, hereby an example of an IsEmpty() quirk (cell "C2" contains a single quote ('), which is typically used for proceeding strings in order to avoid strings being mixed up with numbers):

Edit2: in order to integrate this into your macro, follow this advise:
Your current macro looks like:
For Each xCell In ...
    If Cells(...).Value = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Further processing(...)
Next xCell

Replace this by:
For Each xCell In ...
    If Len(Cells(...).Value) <> 0 Then
    Further processing(...)
    End If
Next xCell


Would be curious to learn what the content of a cell is where Len(cell.Value) is 0 but IsEmpty(cell.Value) is False.

@FunThomas: I've done some basic tests (not putting any value, putting a value and deleting it, putting a value and removing every character) and this seems to indicate that you're right, but I believe there is some weird case where LEN(...) = 0 and IsEmpty(...) give different results.

IsEmpty("") is False, but that's clear because IsEmtpy is supposed to check if a Variant contains any value (VarType <> 0), and "" is VarType=8. But you will never get VarType=8 when you read an empty cell.

@FunThomas: I found a quirk: as you might know, you can proceed numbers with a single quote ' in order to make sure the cell value is to be treated as a string instead of as a number (e.g. left-alignment instead of right). When only putting that single quote character inside a cell, you get a cell, the length of its value being zero, but IsEmpty() yielding FALSE.

@FunThomas: I edited my answer for demonstrating the IsEmpty() quirk.

Yes, makes sense as you explicitly tell Excel that the cell contains a string. But I wouldn't call this a quirk. "Quirk" sounds to me that Excel and/or VBA is not reliable.

@FunThomas: saying that something with zero length is not empty is not very reliable :-)

@Dominique thank you, this is helpful. Using the IF LEN() verification works, however it stops the macro dead in its tracks. Do you know of a way to allow the code to 'resume' on the next row down after it identifies a case where cell.value = 0?

@Bexl: see Edit2
